# How to align horizontally a h1 and a label in one div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align two elements in one line horizontally. Currently, the close button (X) is slightly above the first line of text "BUY THIS" even though they are in the same `div` and I set `flex-direction:row` and `justify-content :space-between`. I want to align them so that they are in the same line horizontally. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h2je4sq7/10/) and my code below:

```js
var dialog= document.querySelector(".tooltip-content");
var openBtn =  document.querySelector(".price-line");
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close");

openBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
dialog.style.display ="block";
});

closeBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
dialog.style.display ="none";
})
```

```css
.close{
  font-size:13px;
}

.price-line{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.tooltip-first{
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.tooltip-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.tooltip-msg{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.tooltip-footer {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 5px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.tooltip .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}

.tooltip {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content {
/*   display:none;
   */  
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}



.tooltip .tooltip-content::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content {
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 90%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px">

</div>

<div class="tooltip">
  <label for="clickable">
     <div class="price-line">price tag</div>
  </label>
  <div class="tooltip-content">       
    <div class ="tooltip-first">
      <h1 class="tooltip-title">BUY THIS</h1>
      <label for="closeCheck">
        <div class="close">
                &#x2715;
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <p class="tooltip-msg"> ON A SALE</p>
    <p class="tooltip-footer"> *BUY NOW</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you are looking for?

```js
var dialog= document.querySelector(".tooltip-content");
var openBtn =  document.querySelector(".price-line");
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close");

openBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
dialog.style.display ="block";
});
closeBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
dialog.style.display ="none";
})
```

```css
.close{
  font-size:13px;
}

.price-line{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.tooltip-first{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.tooltip-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}
.tooltip-msg{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.tooltip-footer {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 5px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.tooltip .close-container {
  display: block;
}

/* .tooltip .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
} */

.tooltip {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content {
/*   display:none;
   */  
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}



.tooltip .tooltip-content::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content {
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 90%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px">

</div>

<div class="tooltip">
  <label for="clickable">
     <div class="price-line">price tag</div>
  </label>
  <div class="tooltip-content">       
    <div class ="tooltip-first">
      <h1 class="tooltip-title">BUY THIS</h1>
      <label for="closeCheck" class="close-container">
        <div class="close">
                &#x2715;
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <p class="tooltip-msg"> ON A SALE</p>
    <p class="tooltip-footer"> *BUY NOW</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `align-items:center`, on `.tooltip-first`. But for this to work you need `display:flex` on it, and also remove those lines:

```
.tooltip .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

Here is the hole code (I added comments for the lines I added or changed):

```js
var dialog= document.querySelector(".tooltip-content");
var openBtn =  document.querySelector(".price-line");
var closeBtn = document.querySelector(".close");

openBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
dialog.style.display ="block";
});
closeBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
dialog.style.display ="none";
})
```

```css
.close{
  font-size:13px;
}

.price-line{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.tooltip-first{
  display:flex; /* line I added */
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:center; /* line I added */
}
.tooltip-title {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.tooltip-msg{
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.tooltip-footer {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 5px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

/* lines I added commented */
/*
.tooltip .close{
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
*/

.tooltip {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content {
/*   display:none;
   */  
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content {
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltip-content::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 90%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 300px">

</div>

<div class="tooltip">
  <label for="clickable">
     <div class="price-line">price tag</div>
  </label>
  <div class="tooltip-content">       
    <div class ="tooltip-first">
      <h1 class="tooltip-title">BUY THIS</h1>
      <label for="closeCheck">
        <div class="close">
                &#x2715;
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <p class="tooltip-msg"> ON A SALE</p>
    <p class="tooltip-footer"> *BUY NOW</p>

  </div>
</div>
```